# can socket.getInputStream().read() read all data after keep send without read()?

Tags: java, sockets

I have one network app and have one puzzle:

If I send data(socket.getOutputStream.write()) for **many** times without call `socket.getInputStream().read()`?
**after minutes.**
can `socket.getInputStream().read()`  read all data for the all sent data?

If can, if over buffer occurred if sent data too huge for minutes or hours?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: I want to write one app : sometimes need response data,sometimes no need response, if read() return all data , I can't distinguish response data by seqnumber or id but just response time.

Comment: Is this really to do with socket.io?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Either anything you write to the socket will be read, or the connection will be terminated. If you don't get an error, then you will *always* read everything you wrote.

If you fill up whatever buffer space is available, then the *sender*'s `write` call will wait until there's more buffer space. It will not raise an error.

Comment: 3ks, how to set buffer space for client?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As long as the socket is still open, because TCP sockets provide [*reliable transmission*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Reliable_transmission).

In practice, the socket might be [forced closed](https://superuser.com/questions/146207/force-socket-close). But yes, forcing the server to use a lot of memory buffers is one common vector in a DDOS attack.

Comment: how to let the server close the socket? keep alive ?

Answer (score 0):

Ye, but if you never read from the socket, the sender might block, which might prevent it from reading, which might block *your* writes.

It isn't a good idea. If the peer is sending responses, read them as the application protocol requires.

Comment: the sender might block? why? if so, I create many client with my defined behave. will it cause the server down or blocked?